# Is the count regression model valid in this use case?

Tags: multiple-regression, count-data, lstm

I was doing a project where my target variable is a count variable. So naturally my mind went to Poisson regression, but upon further inspection, any identical set of
my explanatory variables can result in multiple values of the target variable.

Will my model work under this case, or should I apply something like LSTM?

I am new to ML and would like some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any identical set of my explanatory variables can result in multiple values of the target variable.

That's to be expected in a Poisson model. A standard Poisson regression models the log of the average number of counts as a function of a linear predictor, which is based on covariate values and regression coefficients. But the actual observed values vary about that mean, as the variance of a Poisson-distributed variable equals its mean.

For example, say that the linear predictor for one set of predictor values gives a mean of 1 count. Then only about 37% of observations would have a count value of 1. The same fraction of observations would have a value of 0, and about 18% would have a value of 2. You can explore this behavior yourself with the `dpois()` function in R. For example:

```
print(dpois(0:5,lambda=1),digits=2)
# [1] 0.3679 0.3679 0.1839 0.0613 0.0153 0.0031
```

gives the probability of finding each of 0 through 5 counts when the mean count is 1.

Similarly, different sets of predictor values can result in the same number of observed counts in many cases. Say that a second set of values gives a predicted mean of 2 counts. There's a lot of overlap in the distribution of count values with what's seen with a mean of 1 count.

```
print(dpois(0:5,lambda=2),digits=2)
# [1] 0.135 0.271 0.271 0.180 0.090 0.036
```

You might, however, need to go beyond a simple Poisson model if the dispersion around model predictions differs substantially from the strict "variance equals mean" assumption of a Poisson model. A "quasi-Poisson" or a negative-binomial model can handle that situation while respecting the count-based nature of your outcome values.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I should really spend some time studying the models and their inner workings, I spent half my time dreading that I'll have to code for an LSTM model.

Comment: Just wanted to ask, is there any way to incorporate weights into this Regression model on python or R? Each of the identical set of predictors have multiple target values as I said, but each target value has a weight as well.

Comment: @RockyBalboa there is a `weights` argument to `glm()` in R, but read the help page to see if that's appropriate for the type of weights that you have. In particular: "Non-NULL `weights` can be used to indicate that different observations have different dispersions (with the values in weights being inversely proportional to the dispersions)... For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes: they would rarely be used for a Poisson GLM." Perhaps your study is one of those rare cases.